# Where are Windows theme constants defined?

Tags: windows, drawing, themes

I'm looking through the Microsoft MFC source file winctrl3.cpp and I see references to 3 symbols `CBS_UNCHECKEDNORMAL`, `CBS_CHECKEDNORMAL`, and `CBS_UNCHECKEDDISABLED` for drawing the check state of a checkbox. I'd like to know what the other choices are so I go searching the source files included with Visual Studio but I'm coming up empty, the single occurrence in winctrl3.cpp is the only one found.

I finally found an online [Microsoft reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(VS.85).aspx) which tells me the values should be defined in `Vsstyle.h` and/or `Vssym32.h`, but I can't find those files in my Visual Studio 2005 installation or anywhere else on my system. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's installed as part of the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) on my system (version 7, in my particular case).  It may be that you need to perform a full SDK install to get that particular file or it may be a fairly recent addition to the SDK (i.e., more recent than the SDK included with Visual Studio 2005).